# Caliburn.Micro messes up the conventional binding of a Button?

Tags: caliburn.micro

I have just fired up a WPF project and I want to use Caliburn.Micro.

I have a button

```
<Button Content="Button" Name="AppendData">
```

and in my ViewModel I have a method `void AppendData(){..}`

It doesn't work! There is no binding between the two! But when I do this

```
<Button Content="Button" cal:Message.Attach="AppendData()">
```

it suddenly works. What can be the cause of this?

**Edit:**
I have created a test application where the conventions doesn't work: http://ge.tt/8sNsu201?c
You can make it work, by replacing the controls in MyView with

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="SetText()"  Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,153,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
<Label Content="{Binding Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="124,104,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Comment: Have you followed all of the conventions correctly ? Can you show us a picture representing the tree structure of your project ?

Comment: Yes. However, what other conventions are needed for this simple example to work?

Comment: If you can show us the project tree structure I would be able to help you further, Can you do that please ?

Comment: There is no difference between the two ways, because the first one actually is translated to the other one by Caliburn.Micro, so this is weird. I need to see how you set up the project, or if you are using Visual Studio 2010 or a previous version then I would love if you could upload the project for me and I will take a closer look at it.

Comment: I'm using VS2013, but I won't be able to post the structure until I return to work monday.

Comment: By project tree structure, you mean the files in folders?

Comment: Your method is `private`.

Comment: Yes, didn't get the public access modifier in the copy/paste. Changed.

Comment: Do you use the `Name` tag for the button? Try `x:Name`!

Comment: `Name` and `x:Name` produce the same result.

Comment: @lejon Yes I mean the files in folders.

Answer (score 2):

After taking a look at your source code, I noticed a major mistake which is causing all of this confusion:

```
public MyView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MyViewModel(); // SOURCE OF TROUBLE
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

In Caliburn.Micro you don't set the `DataContext` for your view manually like that, instead you let Caliburn.Micro use its conventions to find the appropriate view for your view-model, then it will bind the two together *(by setting the view-model as the `DataContext` of the view)*, after that it will apply a number of conventions to make everything work correctly.

Explaining why using `cal:MessageAttach()` would work and directly using `AppendData` won't work would take a lot of explanation because it seems you don't know the basics of CM.

So I advise you to take a look at the [**documentation wiki**](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/documentation) first and go through the first 5 articles at least, then here is a hint that will help you discover why the first method worked and the second didn't:

> Message Bubbling

Comment: Just an additional note, because one could miss the subtlety "... for your view **like that**". Generally a view first approach is possible in CM. you should use either `View.Model` or `Bind.Model`/`Bind.ModelWithoutContext` depending on the fact that you are using a view-model-first or view-first approach.

Comment: I see. What is the approach then for View-First that will make the code work? The problem I have with View-Model-First is that is doesn't really show up nice in the designer.

Comment: @lejon: I have added an answer :)

Comment: @ebeeb I agree but I couldn't tell the OP everything about it because he didn't seem to know the basics of Caliburn.Micro, so I pointed him to start with the documentation where he can get heads up and dig into the details further.

Comment: @lejon ebeeb's answer should be useful. Also you can make view-model first work correctly with the designer by using design time support. Anyway as I said start with the documentation first, so you can walk step by step.

Comment: @Sniffer I simply cannot find any documentation on the wiki on how to get started with view-first or view-model-first in WPF without it being loaded from the bootstrapper.

Comment: @lejon What do you mean by "without it being loaded from the bootstrapper". If you are doing what I think you are doing, please don't because it it isn't the right way to do things.

Comment: @Sniffer I mean `public class AppBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<ShellViewModel>`.

Comment: @lejon It is doable but you won't find anything about it because it is not the recommended nor the right way to do it.

Comment: @Sniffer What is the recommended and right way of doing it? Suppose I have a window (ShellView) and I want to add two UserControls (i.e. view with corresponding view models) via CM.

Answer (score 1):

Because this would expand the comments maximum length, I write it as an answer.

As you mentioned in your answer, doing `DataContext = new MyViewModel()` is a kind of code smell in CM. If you want to hook up it manually in your view, this would be the right way (**view first**). Check out the CM documentation regarding this one though, because I think there might be missing something:

```
var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
var view = this;
ViewModelBinder.Bind(viewModel, view, null);
```

You can accomplish this in the XAML of your view, either. Add the following into the `UserControl` tag of your view (**view first**, as well):

```
xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
cal:Bind.Model="MyViewModel"
```

**View model first** would be done quite the same, in case you are not willing to use the default behavior you described in your answer:

```
xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
cal:View.Model="MyViewModel"
```

I am not sure, but I think you have to add an explicitly named export contract to your view model, if you want to use `View.Model` or `Bind.Model`, but it might be it works without as well. Try it out:

```
[Export("MyViewModel", typeof(MyViewModel))]  
public class MyViewModel : Screen  
{  
    // ...
}
```

**Design time views** have nothing to do with **view first** or **view model first** though!
Design-time view support is accomplished as follows:

```
xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:MyViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True"
```

I am currently not able to test all those things, so I hope there are not any mistakes!

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. Can you point to an example of the ViewModel first approach and View first approach?

Comment: Check out the source code of Caliburn.Micro. It contains a variety of samples. Take the [Caliburn.Micro.Hello](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#samples/Caliburn.Micro.Hello/) project as one of many samples for the  view model first approach. They contain also a sample for the view first approach ([Caliburn.Micro.ViewFirst](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#samples/Caliburn.Micro.ViewFirst/))

Comment: I've had a look at the examples, but most of them consists of a single view and viewmodel and not of composite views and viewmodels, which is, I guess, what larger applications end up with.